# Начальная страница - php файл

Tags: javascript, php

Нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php
Там как я понял, есть html, js и php файл. Что делать, если начальная страница - php файл (в смысле главная страница сайта, а отдельного html файла нет). Как изменится код?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: НИКАК не изменится. Для браузера php страница НИЧЕМ не отличается от html страницы

Answer (score 3):

Краткое объяснение про вэб языки:

**HTML** - язык текстовой разметки, то есть то как мы видим сайт

**CSS** - вспомогательный к HTML язык, который помогает создавать style, то есть делать сайт "красивым" разные цвета, обводки и другое. Это можно делать и без него, просто прописав в HTML коде тут css код

**JavaScript (JS)** - язык который отвечает за анимации, нажатии пользователей, и изменение сайта **во время** нахождения пользователя на нем, то есть без перезагрузки страницы

**PHP** - **серверный** язык, который в зависимости от входных данных вам генерируется HTML документ. Например у нас есть PHP файл:

```php
echo "<h1>hello world</h1>";
```

Если его положить на сервер (кстати это можно сделать используя XAMPP), и прописать открыть его в браузере то мы увидим непосредственно HTML файл:

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

То есть, сделав запрос к сайту результат PHP файла будет отправлен человеку. PHP в основном используется чтобы разные люди, в разное время могли видить разный контент на сайте, при этом разработчику не прибигая к изменению HTML файлов.